# Campbell pressure gauge accuracy?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, well-pump

I had a 40/60 well pressure switch leaking and [swapped it out with this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00M8G67I8).  Turned the water back on and noticed it was cutting on at about 42 psi and off at about 63 psi.

Additionally, I checked empty pressure tank psi and it's set to 38.

Wondering how accurate the campbell pressure gauges are; [believe it's this one](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/plumbing/pumps-and-pump-parts/pressure-gauges/4339933?store=14470).  I actually had the entire tank and switch/ gauge/ brass fitting assembly in front of it replaced only a few years ago but my water supply has a very large amount of iron and sediment in it.  So I'm sure that might degrade things quicker.

Should I trust the reading on the gauge and adjust the switch screws to be 40/60 on the gauge?  Or should I replace the gauge as well?

Is there a way to test the accuracy of the gauge?

Thanks

Comment: A few pounds difference won't matter.  As long as it does not go much above 80 pounds, I would not worry about a couple pound difference.  It is easier to adjust a 10 pound change than a couple of pounds if you want it exactly at 60, will probably go under to 56 or 58 on the first time turning.

Comment: A water pressure gauge guaranteed accurate to +/- 1 PSI currently costs more than $100. It's not worth it -- you'll find that the pressure switch stops and starts at random pressures approximating 40/60, sometimes less, sometimes more. An accurate pressure gauge won't change that.

Comment: I guess I'm more concerned about the cut in being 40 psi and the tank at 38.  I read the tank is supposed to be -2psi from the cut in.  Wasn't sure the consequence, if any, there is if it's not exact.